# $watch a factory's function return

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory to manage a standardized current time across my app, which has an exposed function `getTime()`.

I display this on various pages; however, it is not updating as the minutes roll by. I'm trying the below code in my controller and would expect once a minute to get a console log of the current time, but instead it only gets printed each time I actually change the page.

```
    $scope.$watch(function () { return timeService.getTime() }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("$watch", newVal);
            $scope.currentTime = newVal;
        }
    }, true);
```

How can I watch the return value of factory's function?

**Update**

Here is my timeService code

```
    var _getTime = function () {
        return _formatTime(new Date());
    };

    var _formatTime = function (date) {
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
    };
```

Comment: What is `timeService.getTime()` - can you post it?

Comment: @tymeJV updated original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way AngularJS can guess that the value of `timeService.getTime()` changed. Angular runs the digest cycle responding to certain things, like user interaction, that's why it works only on page change. You'd need to manually run `$scope.$apply()` to fix this.

However, since you need a predictable change every 60 seconds, it'd be better to use the `$interval` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service:

```
$interval(function() {
  $scope.currentTime = timeService.getTime()
}, 60 * 1000) // runs every 60 seconds, or 60,000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that new Date() is only getting called once.  So formatTime(new Date()) never changes, hence the watch never gets triggered.  You need the $interval function to keep refreshing the time.  Something like this:

```
_time = $interval(function(){
  $scope.message=new Date();
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options. [**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/cefepacowu/1/edit?html,js,output)

This works for older versions of Angular as well - in 1.2 and higher, you can use the `$interval` service rather than having to use `setInterval` and calling `$apply` to register the update.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <!-- use an object property -->
  <p>time.now --- {{time.now}}</p>
  <!-- use a function as a binding -->
  <p>getTime() --- {{getTime()}}</p>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, time, getTime) {
  $scope.time = time;
  $scope.getTime = getTime;
})
.factory('time', function($rootScope, dateFilter) {
  var time = {};
  function setTime() {
    time.now = dateFilter(Date.now(), 'medium');
  }
  // you can simplify this part to `$interval(setTime, 1000);` in Angular 1.2 or higher
  setInterval(function() {
    $rootScope.$apply(setTime);
  }, 1000);
  setTime();
  return time;
})
.factory('getTime', function($rootScope, dateFilter) {
  var time;
  function setTime() {
    time = dateFilter(Date.now(), 'medium');
  }
  setInterval(function() {
    $rootScope.$apply(setTime);
  }, 1000);
  setTime();
  return function() {
    return time;
  };
})
;
```